# Monaco Editor (react) with extended C# intellisense?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, monaco-editor

I'm using the Monaco-Editor (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react) in react to load some code-files (js,typescript,css).
This works fine out of the box.

Now I would like to load a *.cs-File and realized that c#-intellisense is very basic.
Does anyone know a way to get the full (or at least a better) c# experience (of course not every .net version but maybe 4.7)?

Best regards
Tobias

Comment: What is for you the "full C# experience"? Is it about better syntax highlighting or rather code completion etc.? You question is a bit vague.

Comment: check this repo on github https://github.com/dotnet/try?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website

Comment: @MikeLischke The question is not vague. For C# Monaco offers syntax highlighting but no code completion. For this you need to contextualise the C# code you're editing like the .NET version, and external assemblies... The example on monaco website shows a code sample that is based on the creation of a new language, but by doing this, you lose syntax highlighting. As both syntax highlighting and code completion are desired, Tobias talks about "full C# XP". Very clear question for anybody already dealt with Monaco. (I'm here because, like Tobias, I am wondering as well how to get this full XP)